# Job storing using elasticsearch and c#

Tags: c#, quartz.net, elasticsearch-net

I have created job based on quartz.net which persist the job store information in RAM. 
I would like the persist the job store information in elasticsearch so that if I restart the server it runs the job based on status stored in elasticsearch. Due to some constraint I can't use any database. Is there any way to do it? I have found some useful link and I don't know how it is compatible in .net and the below plugin/code is working properly or not..

https://github.com/viskan/quartz-elasticsearch-jobstore

If you have any alternate idea or any tool for creating the job and storing the job status in elasticsearch please mentioned.

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I think the aspect you are missing is that Quartz.Net is a PORT OVER of java "Quartz".
And the code you found is for the java version of Quartz, not Quartz.Net.

The short answer is "No, you can't do that". (with existing code)

The long answer is that you need to write your own datastore concrete class.

Since you don't want to use any of the following:

```
https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html

Currently following database providers are supported:
SqlServer-20 - SQL Server driver for .NET Framework 2.0
OracleODP-20 - Oracle’s Oracle Driver
OracleODPManaged-1123-40 Oracle’s managed driver for Oracle 11
OracleODPManaged-1211-40 Oracle’s managed driver for Oracle 12
MySql-50 - MySQL Connector/.NET v. 5.0 (.NET 2.0)
MySql-51 - MySQL Connector/:NET v. 5.1 (.NET 2.0)
MySql-65 - MySQL Connector/:NET v. 6.5 (.NET 2.0)
SQLite-10 - SQLite ADO.NET 2.0 Provider v. 1.0.56 (.NET 2.0)
Firebird-201 - Firebird ADO.NET 2.0 Provider v. 2.0.1 (.NET 2.0)
Firebird-210 - Firebird ADO.NET 2.0 Provider v. 2.1.0 (.NET 2.0)
Npgsql-20 - PostgreSQL Npgsql
```

You would write your own.  Or you can get the java version of the code you found, and port it to C#.

That is a lot of work.

Thus why most people choose to figure out some way to use one of the existing "stores".